# Getting the total CPU usage in python 3 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, psutil

I am trying to write a program that can measure the overall CPU usage.

I tried using `psutil.cpu_percent()`,
but it is returning the CPU usage for only the python process.

Comment: According to the documentation `psutil.cpu_percent()` returns the CPU utilization for the whole system. What makes you belive this isn't true in your case?

Comment: when I look at the windows task manager it will show something like 45 percent cpu usage and it will show that python is using 5 percent and that is what python is shoing for me

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil
psutil.cpu_percent(5)
```

Count it for multiple seconds, will return the average cpu usage in 5 seconds.
psutil.cpu_percent() Only gets the usage in the current moment, Which can go from 1 to 50+ in a few ms.